# Angular upload text file then get content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I'm trying to figure out how to read a text/xml file's content which is uploaded onto my WebApp. At this point I don't want/need to hit the server, I simply want to get the file's content/text.

Here's what I have done so far:
**xmlDiff.html:**

```
<div id="xmlDiff-div" class="wrapper">
    <div class="configurationView ">
        <div class="panelHeader">Upload XML Files</div>
        <div class="treeWrapper panelBody">
            <button ngf-select="uploadLeftFile($file)" accept="xml/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="2MB">
                Upload Left File</button>
            <br><br>
            <button ngf-select="uploadRightFile($file)" accept="xml/*" ngf-max-height="1000" ngf-max-size="2MB">
                Upload Right File</button>
            <br><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="diff_editors_div">
        <div class="panelheader sectionHeader">XML Diff Results</div>
        <div id="compare"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, here's my controller:

```
app.controller('XmlDiffCtrl', ['$scope', '$q', '$location', '$timeout', function ($scope, $q, $location, $timeout) {
    $('#compare').mergely({
        cmsettings: {readOnly: false, lineNumbers: true},
        ignorews: true,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        lhs: function (setValue) {
            setValue('paste left XML here');
        },
        rhs: function (setValue) {
            setValue('paste right XML here');
        }
    });
    $scope.uploadRightFile = function (file) {
        console.log("Upload Right File has been called");
        console.log("file content :" + file);
        $scope.rightFileText = file.data; **doesn't work, need an alternative**

    };
    $scope.uploadLeftFile = function (file) {

    };
}]);
```

Just as a note, I'm a beginner Angular developer so if anyone wants to bash my Angular skills go right ahead, but I primarily need help with figuring out how to access the file's content after uploading.

Let me know if I haven't been clear enough if y'all need more details.

Comment: [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader) maybe?

Comment: When you say you want to "get" the file's content, do you mean that you want to display it on the screen after it is selected?  Like a thumbnail that shows the selected file?

Comment: Yeah I actually want to display it in the mergely editor, but basically what you're saying yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function handleFiles(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
  $scope.rightFileText = e.target.result; }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

Comment: What exactly is e.target.result ?

Comment: Tried what you said and I got the obvious error since 'e' doesn't exist and:
'code' 
angular.js:12416 Error: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': The object is already busy reading Blobs.
xmlDiffController.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
 'code'

Comment: did you see i just edited it ?  or you can try to use "this.result"

Comment: I'm not sure if you can display a text file in a View.  I know how to open and display it in a window.  Will that help?